# All list items are created by RecyclerViewAdapter. How to properly set RecyclerView in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView in fragment. The problem is with invoking every element by RecyclerAdapter during displaying fragment. The `onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` methods invoke for every possible elements in list, not only for visible elements.

I've tried solutions with `android:layout_height` setting on `wrap_content`, `match_parent` and `0dp` with `constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`

The only possible way I've found that RecyclerView adapter invoke only for visible elements (fragment_learn_choose_content.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_learn_choose_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp" />
</layout>
```

But `android:layout_height="600dp"` is hardcoded, and I`d like to avoid this.

My Fragment:

```
public class LearnChooseContentFragment {
    private LearnChooseContentMenuRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private List<LearnContent> listOfContents;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listOfContents = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new LearnChooseContentMenuRecyclerAdapter(listOfContents);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        FragmentLearnChooseContentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_learn_choose_content, container, false);
        RecyclerView list = binding.recyclerViewLearnChooseContent;
        list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        list.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(list.getContext()));
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onEvent(Service service) {
        ...
        listOfContents.clear();
        adapter.setList(someList);
    }
```

My RecyclerAdapter class (LearnChooseContentMenuRecyclerAdapter):

```
class LearnChooseContentMenuRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private final List<LearnContent> list;

LearnChooseContentMenuRecyclerAdapter(List<LearnContent> list) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    ItemLearnContentBinding bindingContentItem = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.item_learn_content, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(bindingContentItem);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            viewHolder.bind(list.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void setList(List<LearnContent> newList){
    final LearnContentDiffCallback diffCallback = new LearnContentDiffCallback(list, newList);
    final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback);

    list.clear();
    list.addAll(newList);
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}

public List<LearnContent> getList() {
    return list;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ItemLearnContentBinding binding;
    private LearnContent content;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull ItemLearnContentBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    public void bind(LearnContent learnContent){
        setItem(learnContent);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
    }

    public void setItem(LearnContent learnContent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you show use the recyclerviewadapter code ?

Comment: Why is this a problem that the adapter invoke onCreateViewHolder() for every item in list?

Comment: It should not invoke on every item it should invoke only on visible items, if you can edit your question with the adapter code so we can help you in a better way

Comment: @MaksimNovikov because this is a list of 150 elements, and when `onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` are invoked for every element it slow down app.

Comment: Are you sure that the adapter is invoking on every element ? on 150 elements ?? because if there is 5 items visible the adapter may invoke on 5 - 10 elements

Comment: Add a log in this methods to see which elements actually invoked, the adapter can call those methods multiple time for each element and this can make you think that more than needed elements called.

Comment: @AntoineElMurr I've added adapter class. I'm sure that it invoke for every element in list, because I checked it on debugger. I also checked how many times adapter is called, and is called only once.